# SI4T Index data and Dynamic preview

Tags: dd4t, si4t

SI4T is adding index data as XML to the package during rendering of an item, XML Fragment is stripped out by the storage extension during deployment.
But in case of Dynamic Preview (XPM Session Preview), The storage extenstion is not executed by the Session preview odata webservice.

In a DD4T implementation, the DD4T de-serialization will fail because of the additional Indexing data XML.

Is there any fix for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Generate Index Data](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/develop/tbbs/GenerateIndexData.cs) TBB includes a function called `IsTargetIndexed`, which looks like it's intended to prevent the output from being generated when using Session Preview. It calls `IsFastTrackPublishing` in the [`TemplateBase`](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/a577bce9ee6384e4c2c1a72864a4d232521e4d7e/tbbs/Common/TemplateBase.cs).

Are your TBBs up to date?

Comment: Thanks, David, I have updated my Tbb's with the dev branch.

Comment: Good detective work! The idea of that function IsTargetIndexed is that in future the presence of a search index might be something managed by the new Topology manager thing, so it could be used to control if SI4T should be 'activated' in the TBBs.